# f is defined by $f:x\mapsto x-2$ and g is a function such that $g\circ f:x\mapsto\frac{1}{11-3x}$ , $x≠ \frac{11}{3}$ Find the function g

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

The function $f$ is defined by $f:x\mapsto x-2$  and another function $g$ is such that

$$g\circ f:x\mapsto \frac{1}{11-3x} , x≠\frac{11}{3}$$

Find the function $g$.

Comment: Is $gf$ compsoition or product?

Comment: composition, i think

Comment: Yeah, maybe its composition otherwise the solution is trivial.

Comment: You know that $(g \circ f)(x)=1 / (11-3x) = h(x)\,$. Then $g = h \circ f^{-1}$ where $f^{-1}$ is easy to determine.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(x) = x-2
$$
$$
g(f(x)) = \frac{1}{11-3x}
$$
$$
g(x-2) = \frac{1}{11-3x}
$$
Substitute $t = x-2$
$$
g(t) = \frac{1}{11-3(t+2)} = \frac{1}{5-3t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean $gf$ as a composition, then $g(x)=\frac{1}{5-3x}$.